# Why does Pygame image automatically gets a peculiar pixelated outline on scaling?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a chess game in Python using Pygame, and I'm facing problems while scaling images. Whenever I try to scale an image, it gets a **pixelated outline**, like a really sharp shape.

Say for example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeb8c.png) is the image of a Pawn (`wp.png`) which I'm trying to import. The dimensions are `314*314`. But after I scale the image to another value, it gets pixelated like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4TOy.png).

Following is the code which I find useful to help solve the problem:

```
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 400
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION

def load_images():
    global IMAGES
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = pygame.image.load('Images/' + piece + '.png')
        IMAGES[piece] = pygame.transform.scale(IMAGES[piece], (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) for pygame.transform.scale(): "This is a fast scale operation that does not sample the results."

For a better looking result you can instead use [pygame.transform.smoothscale()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale).

If your target size is always going to be the same, you may get better results resizing the image manually in an image editor to avoid needing to scale it during runtime at all.